# Laptop with matte screen and non-widescreen aspect ratio

Tags: laptop, displays

I am looking for laptop with taller screen (i.e. aspect ratio 3:2 or better (4:3, 5:4, whatever... just not 16:9 or 16:10), and **matte screen**.

I found it especially tricky to look for laptops with matte screen today. Most of the manufacturers don't put this information in their specs and many databases have false data. For example an awesome database [notebookcheck.net](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Laptop-Search.8223.0.html#results) does allow to filter `3:2 aspect ratio` and `glossy: no`, but it will say that [Huawei Matebook X Pro](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Huawei-MateBook-X-Pro-i7.290546.0.html) is matte while [it's glossy](https://youtu.be/t4O7VQOYS1M?t=117), and it will say that [Acer Swift 3 is glossy](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Swift-3-SF313-52-52AS.494077.0.html)  while [it's matte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1VIHS9068Y).

Also my favourite store alza.cz does allow to filter by aspect ratio and mattness/glossiness, but also seem to have false information, e.g. it says that [Huawei Matebook 13 is matte](https://www.alza.cz/huawei-matebook-13-2020-space-gray-d5893097.htm#discussionPosts) while [it's glossy](https://youtu.be/_Lv0XcUs2i8?t=57).

Or am I wrong because these models have both matte/glossy variants?

It seems a big mess in this so please, **are there any  non-widescreen laptops with matte screen?**

<sub>(only found that Acer Swift 3)</sub>

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you desiring a matte screen for any functional purposes? The only laptops I can think of that had matte screens are some Chromebooks, and ThinkPad's. I don't really recall any laptops that aren't in a 16:9-10 ratio.